# Javascript: How to show/hide between two div using radiobutton?

Tags: javascript, html, css, radio-button

I have problems on hiding/showing an image using radio-buttons with JavaScript. What I want to do is that, when loading the page, only the first image will be shown by default while the second image is hidden. Then the user can choose which one to show or hide when clicking the radio-buttons.

Here's a snippet of what I've done so far.

```
<input type="radio" name="img1" onclick="img(0)" checked>Image 1
<input type="radio" name="img2" onclick="img(1)">Image 2

<div id="img1">
  <!-- insert image -->
</div>
<div id="img2">
  <!-- insert image -->
</div>


<script>
  function img(x){
    if(x==0){
      document.getElementById('img2').style.display='none';
      document.getElementById('img1').style.display='block';
    }
    else{
      document.getElementById('img1').style.display='none';
      document.getElementById('img2').style.display='block';
    }
    return;
  }
</script>
```

The problem in here is that, after loading the page, the two image is shown. The second image will only be hidden after clicking the radio-button for the first image and vice versa. Also, the **checked** attribute is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set default to display none

```
<div id="img2" style="display:none;">
  <!-- insert image -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked but the image didn't render properly.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your approach is that by adding more images, your validation to hide and show will become incrementally more complex and that will not be nice in the future. You should try something a bit more flexible, i ll give you an example solution with 3 images so it is easier to get my point.

Note: the "name" tag in the input is what will create the "radio group", so they all need to be the same, or you will end up with multiple active radios at the same time.

The inputs to select which image is visible, i decided to pass the id of the image cause it makes it easier to search for it in the next step

```
<span><input type="radio" name="image-selector" onclick="handler('img1')" checked>Image 1</span>
<span><input type="radio" name="image-selector" onclick="handler('img2')">Image 2</span>
<span><input type="radio" name="image-selector" onclick="handler('img3')">Image 3</span>
```

The images, the display none on the 2 and 3 will make sure only the first one is visible on start there is also an extra class image that will make it easier to hide all of them and show only the one we want if we end up with multiple images

```
<div id="img1" class="image">1</div>
<div id="img2" class="image" style="display:none">2 </div>
<div id="img3" class="image" style="display:none">3</div>
```

Finally the handler function that will show and hide your images, the advantage here is that you can add more images to your html without ever needing to change this function

```
function handler(x) {
      // get the list of all images and convert the html collection to an array
      var imagesArray = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('image'))

      // cycle the array to show the one selected and hide all the others
      imagesArray.forEach(ele => {
        if(ele.id === x) {
          ele.style.display = 'block'
        } else {
          ele.style.display = 'none'
        }
      })
  }
```

Some information regarding things i used that you didnt use yourself

**html collection**: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_htmlcollection.asp

**getElementsByClassName**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

**arrays forEach** : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: It worked. Thanks! But I have problem on the **display: none**. When I clicked on the button for the second image, it won't render properly. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @Semb you sure you didnt have any typo in the code? like missing a class, or not passing the correct id something like that?

Answer (score 0):

The radio group must have share the same name (the value of the name attribute) to be treated as a group.

Try running the snippet below:

```js
function img(x) {
  if (x == 0) {
    document.getElementById('img2').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('img1').style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('img1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('img2').style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

```html
    <input type="radio" name="img" onclick="img(0)" checked>Image 1
    <input type="radio" name="img" onclick="img(1)">Image 2

    <div id="img1">
        1
    </div>
    <div id="img2" style="display: none;">
        2
    </div>
```

Comment: I tried doing this but the second image won't show. I suppose the name is like an identifier for which image will be shown. The **checked** attribute worked properly now though.

Comment: Make sure your second url is valild.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <input type="radio" name="img" value="img1"  onclick="img(0)"  checked> img 1<br>
      <input type="radio" name="img" value="img2"  onclick="img(1)" > img 2<br>

    <div id="img1">
      jfdhgjfd
    </div>
    <div id="img2" style="display:none;">
     gfdgfd
    </div>


    <script>
      function img(x){
        if(x==0){
          document.getElementById('img2').style.display='none';
          document.getElementById('img1').style.display='block';
        }
        else{
          document.getElementById('img1').style.display='none';
          document.getElementById('img2').style.display='block';
        }
        return;
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: Hi! The same problem I encountered with @RafiHenig's answer. The second image won't show. I suppose the name is like an identifier for which image will be shown.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this also without JS

```css
.img {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 28px;
}

input:checked + .img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label for="radio1">Image 1</label>
<input id="radio1" type="radio" name="img" checked>
<div class="img">
  1
</div>
<label for="radio2">Image 2</label>
<input id="radio2" type="radio" name="img">
<div class="img">
  2
</div>
```

But the `.img` should stay right after the radio input.

Or more generic JS version which works regardless of the number of images

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".imageSelection").forEach(el => {
  el.onclick = event => {
    const id = event.target.dataset.imageToShow
    document.querySelectorAll(".img").forEach(img => { img.style.display = "none" })
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block"
  }
})
```

```html
<label for="radio1">Image 1</label>
<input id="radio1" type="radio" name="img" class="imageSelection" checked data-image-to-show="img1">

<label for="radio2">Image 2</label>
<input id="radio2" type="radio" name="img" class="imageSelection" data-image-to-show="img2">


<div class="img" id="img1">
  1
</div>
<div class="img" id="img2" style="display: none">
  2
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I would like to provide example of Radio button without any JavaScript. The same thing can be acheived without the use of JavaScript. However it might be good if few number of radio buttons, But not useful for more radio buttons. Also, we can use SCSS for such cases.

I hope this will be helpful.

```css
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans';

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body { 
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}


.tab-content {
  display: none;
}

input.radio-tab[value="1"]:checked ~ #tabOne {
  display: block;
}

input.radio-tab[value="2"]:checked ~ #tabTwo {
  display: block;
}

input.radio-tab[value="3"]:checked ~ #tabThree {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="radio-wrapper">
 <input type="radio" class="radio-tab" name="radioTabTest" value="1" id="tab1" checked />
 <label for="tab1">Tab 1</label>
 
 <input type="radio" class="radio-tab" name="radioTabTest" value="2" id="tab2" />
 <label for="tab2">Tab 2</label>
 
 <input type="radio" class="radio-tab" name="radioTabTest" value="3" id="tab3" />
 <label for="tab3">Tab 3</label>
 
 <div id="tabOne" class="tab-content">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/01/08/11/57/butterfly-1127666_960_720.jpg" height="200"/>
 </div>
 
 <div id="tabTwo" class="tab-content">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/02/08/22/27/flower-3140492_960_720.jpg" height="200"/>
 </div>
 
 <div id="tabThree" class="tab-content">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/05/05/02/37/sunset-1373171_960_720.jpg" height="200"/>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This one:

```
<script>function img(x){
if(x==0){
  document.querySelector("#img1").style.visibility = "visible";
  document.querySelector("#img1").style.display = "block";
  document.querySelector("#img2").style.visibility = "hidden";
  document.querySelector("#img2").style.display = "none";
}
else{
  document.querySelector("#img2").style.visibility = "visible";
  document.querySelector("#img2").style.display = "block";
  document.querySelector("#img1").style.visibility = "hidden";
  document.querySelector("#img1").style.display = "none";
}
return;}</script>
```